# Need help on Angularjs Filteration

Tags: php, json, angularjs, wordpress

I am working on WordPress website.

I have a JSON data as following:

```
{"id":355,"title":"ZISIMOPOULOS LTD","cat":{"1":"Contractor - High Pressure","2":"Cutting &amp; Breaking","3":"Hydrodemolition","4":"Surface Preparation - UHP","5":"Tube, Pipe &amp; Bundle Cleaning"},"link":"http:\/\/localhost\/members\/zisimopoulos-ltd\/","memberType":"C1 - Water Jetting Contractor","email":"info@zisimopoulos.gr","telephone":"302104412004","fax":"302104416524","website":"www.zisimopoulos.gr"}
```

Each member is associated to more than one categories like on above data:

```
"cat":{"1":"Contractor - High Pressure","2":"Cutting &amp; Breaking","3":"Hydrodemolition","4":"Surface Preparation - UHP","5":"Tube, Pipe &amp; Bundle Cleaning"}
```

I have to list all the unique categories on the left side of the page with the checkbox for each category next to it, which I have done.

Now i need to filter the data, when clicking on each category in the left side of the page. Multiple checkbox can be clicked.

Below is the screenshot of what I trying to achieve. Categories on left, on clicking the checkbox will filter the result.

http://tinypic.com/r/zt6hhz/8

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Here is the link of the screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/zt6hhz/8, which I am trying to achieve. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This can probably save you a lot of trouble, http://codecanyon.net/item/taxonomy-metadata-searching-plugin-angular-js/8916111